# JavaScript library for Time and Date Fields

Tags: javascript, html

What's the best, free JavaScript library to work with time and date fields in a JSP project?

Here are my needs:

- Formatting should be customizable.
- For a date field, a date picker popup would be a plus.
- Does not allow the user to enter invalid characters, much like the time field in Windows clock.
- Does not depend on jQuery. Nothing against jQuery, but my project isn't ready to commit to it yet.

If there's one from Apache or SourceForge, that would be great!

Or should I make one myself? :(

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a nice standalone one: http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/date-picker-v4/ It meets most but not all of your criteria. It's from this list, of which the first seven (!) are jQuery-specific: http://www.bitrepository.com/a-collection-of-free-javascript-date-pickers.html Commenting rather than answering because A) I haven't used it, and B) It doesn't satisfy your third bullet (but look and see if you can live with that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date.js is a very good library, and has validation functions too... but it doesn't offer UI support, so it should be matched with some additional components.

http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: ...but...it's not a date picker. Yes, fantastic lib, have recommended it several times. It's just, as an *answer*, it kinda falls at the first hurtle, y'know?

Comment: I've decided to go with one of the libraries from the site T.J. linked. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score -1):

jquery datepicker

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: You've ignored the fourth bullet: *"Does not depend on jQuery. Nothing against jQuery, but my project isn't ready to commit to it yet."*